# Hibernate ManyToOne, duplicate key in join table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a three tables in my database, one for Houses, and one for Users.
Users can have many houses in this case.

each House have a unique generated Id(PK). And users have their username as Id(PK). And users have a Collection in their class with house objects.

Lets say user foo adds 3 houes which has the keys; 1, 2, 3 and then user bar then goes along and adds the house with key 1, then I get hibernate error, that says I have duplicate key.

```
sep. 28, 2015 2:06:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_r5dofs84kmj9k4a73t03avcce'
sep. 28, 2015 2:06:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

I was looking around ManyToMany, and how some people managed that. But noticed that my house class also would have a Collection with users. Which would have no function in my code at all.

Below is my two classes.

User class

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Houses> houses = new ArrayList<>();

public User() {
}

public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Collection<Houses> getHouses() {
    return houses;
}

public void setHouses(Collection<Marker> houses) {
    this.houses = houses;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
}
```

House class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="house")
public class House{


    private String address; 

    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long projectId; 

    public House() {

    }

    public House(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(long projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I don't know what could be wrong, am I wrong in this is a OneToMany relation?

Comment: if each user can have more than one house and each house can have more than one users(inhabitants) is a many to many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ManyToMany Idea is the right way because you have the situation that one house can belong to many users and one user can have many houses. So i would create something like:
`User.java`

```
//...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "house_user_association", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "projectId")})
private Set<House> houses = new HashSet<>();
//...
```

`House.java`

```
//...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "houses")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
//...
```

And everything should work well.

It will create an join table to map your entity constelation.

**Edit**
For unique many to many you need 
`User.java`

```
//...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "house_user_association", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "house_id", referencedColumnName = "projectId"),
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username", "house_id"})
private Set<House> houses = new HashSet<>();
//...
```

Comment: That got the problem solved. However a new one came to be, I can see that in my databases that by adding to it, it sometimes doublicates it. so that table 'house_user_association' has two rows that are identical. Can I make rows unique?

Comment: i edited my post for uniqueness, but there should be no problem with duplicates if you use sets instead of lists....

Comment: I tried make it work for Set, as my other code depended on that. But I will change it. Thanks alot for the help :)